# Which Laravel Vue best way to manage filtering from filters in Laravel Vue?

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js, filter

I have a page in which, through a form, i can redirect mywebsite to a page, that will show my apartments_list.
I will recover the apartaments list from my database, using data from filters with WHERE keyword, and show it in my apartments_list page.

My apartments_list page will be handled with Vue. That page must have the same filters as the other one. If i modify the filters, the result must change, there mustn't be refresh.

Which is the best way to manage this?
I thought to pass to the apartments_list page two different list:
One is the list_filtered, the other one is the complete list.
If i change the filter in my apartments_list page, through Vue, ill modify a copy of my complete list respecting the filters filtering.

There is a better way to do this?
Im using Laravel and Vue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue.js [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) to achieve this on your Vue.js component.

Let's say you have the full list of Listings on your Vue.js data and want to filter it based on choices.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCity: "Istanbul",
      listings: [], // Apartment Listings, will be filled by the API
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed list of filtered listings
    filteredListings() {
      return this.listings.filter((listing) => {
        return listing.city.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedCity.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Of course you need to edit filtering logic but this is a way to solve your need on Vue.js with a complte list of listings.

A better version can bu set up by watching filter changes and ask a list of filtered result for api on each change. To understand this you can check [Vue.js Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect).